# Get tags of a commit

Tags: python, git, commit, git-tag, gitpython

Given an object of GitPython Commit, how can I get the tags related to this commit?

I'd enjoy having something like:

```
next(repo.iter_commits()).tags
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that tags point to commits, not the other way around.  To get this information would require a linear scan of all tags to find out which ones point to the given commit.  You could probably write something yourself that would do it.  The following would get you a commit-to-tags dictionary:

```
tagmap = {}
for t in repo.tags():
  tagmap.setdefault(r.commit(t), []).append(t)
```

And for a given commit, you can get any tags associated with it from:

```
tags = tagmap[repo.commit(commit_id)]
```

Comment: Thanks. Working with Filetree for a long time got me used to the idea that a tag is associated with a commit and not the other way around

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use something like:
git tag --points-at

Should be quite easy to run from GitPython