# Python git package get tag and commit

Tags: python-3.x, git, gitpython

I would like to print a `git commit` and the tag in my Python code.
How can I do this using `git` package?

When I am going to my Bitbucket I see

```
tag: 73-2-g46b9856

commit checksum: 46b9856
```

How can I retrieve this info from `git` package?

I have done the following:

```
import git
repo = git.Repo(search_parent_directories=True)
sha = repo.head.object.hexsha
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking for. What do you mean by "I would like to print a `git commit`"? Are you searching for a specific commit and want to print an output similar to `git log`? Do you already know the tag?

Comment: @dtc I want to get the checksum and the tag of the last commit

Comment: Often the simplest thing is to shell out to a git subprocess like  git-describe or git-tag or something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what solved my issue:

```
repo = git.Repo(search_parent_directories = True)
sha = repo.head.object.hexsha

commit_chksum = repo.git.rev_parse(sha, short = 7)
tag = subprocess.check_output(["git", "describe", "--always"]).strip().decode()
```

Answer (score 2):

So I assume you already have the checksum you want in the `sha` variable.

At this point, there's a post for how to get the tags and looking for a specific tag associated with that `sha` in this link: [Get tags of a commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34932306/get-tags-of-a-commit)

```
# Example code for clarity

import git
repo = git.Repo(search_parent_directories=True)
sha = repo.head.object.hexsha
tagmap = {}
for t in repo.tags:
  tagmap.setdefault(repo.commit(t), []).append(t)
tags = tagmap[repo.commit(sha)] # Warning: Your latest commit might not have a tag associated with it so this will throw an error right now.
print(tags)
```